# Should not the "Comment formatting" page information be corrected?

Tags: bug, comments, formatting

The [comment formatting page for CG.SE](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) mentions that to add a linebreak to a comment, one just has to

> End a line with two spaces

I tried to add a line break to a comment following above procedure, it did not work.

Should not the "Comment formatting" page information be corrected?
Or alternately, should not the features described by the "Comment formatting" page be supported?

Answer (score 4):

The "end a line with two spaces" bit is not part of the "comment formatting" section. The "comment formatting" section is actually at the very bottom of the page. It just happens so that your link (with the anchor) also displays the requested section at the top for convenience. However, only the yellow part of the top is relevant to comments:

> the above section is quoted for convenience from the full editing help, below.

The rest of the page is for general markdown in posts, where two spaces do indeed end a line.